# Passbook Entitlements?

Tags: ios, passbook, entitlements, passslot

I am using Passslot services to do Passes in an app.  I upload my PassID that I created in Provisioning Profile to Pass slot.  Am I still required to set the entitlements for Passbook within Xcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your app needs to interact with the passes that are inside the user's Passbook (e.g. read, update or delete), you need to add entitlements to your app. 
If your app is just adding a pass to passbook, you don't need entitlements. 
You can find more information in the [Passbook Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Apps.html)

Comment: Can u pl help me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025264/how-can-i-add-values-to-the-pass-using-passslot)?