# How can I add values to the pass using Passslot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, passbook, passslot

I'm integrating [Passlot](https://www.passslot.com) in my app for wallet integration. I'd created new pass type id and added it in Passslot.

I'd created a pass template for type - boarding pass as below,

[image]

And in my app, i'm creating the pass with the above template and a dictionary with values,

```
NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"14", @"gate" ,
                        @"India", @"depart" ,
                        @"UAE", @"arrive" ,
                        @"2:25 PM", @"boardingTime",
                        @"Air India", @"flightNewName" ,
                        @"first", @"class",
                        @"7/22", @"date" ,
                        @"name", @"passenger",nil];

[PassSlot createPassFromTemplateWithName:@"Sample" withValues:values andRequestInstallation:self completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Created");
}];
```

The pass is created, but the values that I'm passing are not there in the pass. It's showing the default values in the pass template.

[image]

I'm passing the values in the dictionary input. why it's not coming?

How can I solve it? Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for PassSlot to be able to show your provided data, you need to tell the system where it should appear on the pass.

For this we have our so called placeholder system. It allows you to define any number of data fields, called placeholders, that can be provided during creation of the pass.

The easiest way to create placeholders on the fly and tell the system where to show the data is by writing `${<name of placeholder>}` on your template. This will automatically create a text placeholder for you.

So in order for your provided gate `14` from to data to appear on the top right of the pass, replace on the template the `23` with `${gate}`. The same you can do with all other provided data as well.

Placeholders are pretty flexible, you can use them anywhere (barcode, backside & non-visible parts) and you can also have multiple placeholders per field (e.g. you could have `PASSENGER` composed of `${firstName} ${lastName}`).
Placeholders can also have different types then text for advanced use cases, you can see and edit them in the placeholders tab when you edit the template.

Comment: I have a query there, how can I add texts to the QR/Barcodes in the passes?

Comment: For labels we can add ${<name of placeholder>}, for QRCodes?

Comment: In order to add a placeholder in the barcode, select it, chose on the right side the dropdown "Data" and select "Custom". Then a input field will appear where you can enter your placeholder. If you need your data to be inside the barcode unaltered, you might need to disable "Sign Barcode".